# How to get all document from couchdb start with some word. is it possible in light couch?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb, java

I am using `pouchdb` on client side and `couchdb` on server side. and both are in sync.

I am accessing couchdb from java using client-api [lightpouch](http://www.lightcouch.org/).

I am storing transaction data, each transaction is stored as document by prefixed _id like 
Transaction_1,
Transaction_2
..
..
so on

**Now i want to access all the documents where the _id field starts with Transaction on the server.**

This is possible in pouchdb and i am able to achieve that.

But i am wondering how can i achieve the same at server side, in java using lightcouch.

Or is there any Java client-API available that provides this kind of functionality. ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find all documents whose `_id`s match a certain prefix, you only need to do:

```
/_all_docs?startkey="foo"&endkey="foo\uffff"
```

(For the prefix `"foo"`.)

I wrote up a bit about why this works [here](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-quick-search#autosuggestions-and-prefix-search).

Answer (score 1):

> LightCouch aims at providing a simple API
>   for communicating with CouchDB databases.

What you need is a CouchDB view server-side which you can request with LightCouch.